# add input to existing dictionary entry without overwriting

Tags: python

im trying to add to a dictionary that looks like the following

```
d = {"feline" : {"lion" : 22,
"tiger" : 88 },
"canine" : {"dog" : 12,
"wolf" : 53,
"coyote" : 77} }
```

im trying to add 'cat' and 55 to the dictionary under feline but im not sure how to acess this. this is what i attempted

```
fp = raw_input("enter a feline type")
apa = input("enter an amount")
for keys in d :
    if fp not in d[keys] :
        d['feline'] = {fp : int(apa)}
```

but when i do this the values such as tiger and lion get deleted and the input is replaced for them. for example if i want to add cat under the 'feline' section, usin the above code i get...

```
{'feline': {'cat ': 55}, 'canine': {'coyote': 77, 'wolf': 53, 'dog': 12}}
```

how do i keep lion and tiger in the dictionary without overwriting them using dictionaries

Comment: First, the whole point of using dictionaries is that you shouldn't have to loop over them (`for keys in d:`) to find out whether a value exists or not. Second, if you really _do_ need to loop over the keys and values of a dict, it's usually easier to write `for key, value in d:` than `for key in d: something_with(d[key])`.

Comment: how do you check if an item exist then? thats how ive always done it

Comment: Use the `in` operator. To check if a key exists in a dictionary, it's just `if key in d`. The same as for sets, and any other collections. But meanwhile, why are you checking for it in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use item assignment like this

```
d['feline']['cat'] = 55
```

For your case, you might want to do,

```
d['feline'][fp] = int(apa)
```

When you say,

```
d['feline'] = {fp : int(apa)}
```

You are replacing whatever is already there in `d['feline']` with a new dictionary (`{fp : int(apa)}`), instead you can add new key and corresponding value like I have shown above.

Comment: I think what the OP may have been _trying_ to do is `d['feline'].update({fp: int(apa)}`, he just didn't know about `update`. That would actually work. But I have no idea why you'd _want_ to do that—it makes much more sense to just assign a value to a key (as this answer does) than to create a dict with one key and value just to `update` from it…

Comment: @abarnert If I have to add more elements to the dict, I would go with `update`, but for a single key-value, that would be an overkill I think.